# firebase update on form submit not working?

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Trying to submit an update to a firebase document -  keep getting errors stating that the document ID isn't available. Unsure how to fix the problem exactly.

The firebase call is this,

```
exports.updateWorkflow = (req, res) => {
  let Workflow = req.body;

  db.doc(`/Workflow/${req.params.WorkflowId}`)
    .update(Workflow)
    .then(() => {
      return res.json({ message: "Details added successfully" });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
    });
};
```

Route is,

```
app.post('/updateWorkflow', updateWorkflow);
```

And using postman i'm submitting

```
http://localhost:5000/xx/xx/api/updateWorkflow/3ejAQxPoJ6Wsqsby01S6
```

With a json body of

```
{
    "claimEoT" : "false"

}



    { Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: No document to update: ...../Workflow/undefined
>      at Object.callErrorFromStatus (....
>    code: 5,
>    details: 'No document to update: p.......',
>    metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map {}, options: {} } }
```

I am trying to make it so I can update the data in the document. It is being used in a wizard form to save state, so basically when I change a variable in the form from true to false, the state changes, and when I click submit, the changes are updates in the document on firebase.

I think it's something to do with how I am creating the firebase call - or something to do with the information I am sending  to the call. Very confused - feel like it should be working really

Comment: Please edit the question to show the exact error message, and the values of all the variables in play here.  We need enough information to exactly reproduce the issue as you're seeing it.  Also please state what you expect this function to do when executed with the given values.

Comment: Done - if you have anymore questions @DougStevenson happy to answer

Comment: 404 means you have the wrong URL to the function.  The function is not even being invoked.  You would be able to see that from the logs in the cloud console.

Comment: Oh okay. That is confusing - I'll pass in the id via Parameters in postman next

Comment: Oh okay, reduceworkflow is not defined it is saying now after passing in parameters

Comment: Okay - now it's the above error, so no workflow is found weirdly!

Comment: Oh I made another small change and that seems to have worked - just by making the post url have another /:WorkflowId input on it

Comment: If you want, post a response and I'll click it as completed, as you managed to spur me onto fixing the issue :D

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to change url to include ../:workflowId